# Accessing google anyaltics API in my aaplication

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I am currently working with the Google Analytics API. I have implemented ga react package, so the analytics tool can show me the required data.

As per my understanding, Google uses OAuth 2.0 to identify the user and grant access. As my application has it's own user(s) and every user is not available in google.

Is it possible to access the Google analytics API inside my application?. API should get called using an only the API key.

So is it possible to access Google analytics API with the only key?

Answer (score 0):

First off let me start by saying im not sure i understand this statement

> As my application has it's own user(s) and every user is not available in google.

I am going to assume that you are trying to show the users of your application the analytics data from a single analytics account which they dont have access to.

## API Keys

Api keys are used to access public data only.  Public data is data that is not owned by any user.  Public Videos on YouTube, Google analytics meta data API, Holiday calendars on google calendar these are all examples of Public data not owned by any user.

## Private data

In order to access private user data you must have the permission of the user who has access to that data.  Google analytics data is private user data you own the data associated with your account.  In order for your application to access that data it  must have your permission to do so.   Permission is grated using Oauth2.

If you will only ever be accessing your own account and you will not be accessing data owned by other users then you could consider using a service account.   Service accounts are dummy users you can share your google analytics account with the service account there by preauthorizing its access and it will then be able to access the data without needing to be logged in all the time.  The issue with service accounts is that it cant be used client side you will need to use server sided code for this.  I am not a react developer so im not sure if thats one of the JavaScript frameworks that can also run server-sided or not.